# Major Server Issue

Tags: 14.04, mysql, wordpress

lately I have been loading my [website](http://joelgillespiephotography.com), and almost every time I do (once or twice a day) the message: "Error establishing a database connection".
I have resolved it temporarily by stopping and starting mysql using 'service mysql stop' then 'service mysql start'.

My website works after I send these commands over ssh.

However this is recurring, every time I load my website, say the next day, I get the same error.

My server is running Ubuntu 14.04 (DigitalOcean) and has mysql, phpmyadmin and wordpress installed.

Can anyone give my some advice on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the log file?

```
less /var/log/messages

less /var/log/syslog
```

As for me, first time over at Digital Ocean I burned myself not setting up a swapfile and with the 500mb RAM I quickly learned that this was needed. (e.g. services/server crashed) Maybe you have more memory available, still worth checking.

You can check with:

```
sudo swapon -s
```

If this is the issue, please see their howto on to do this: [How-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)